# Renderizar una consulta en base a opciones de un select en Django

Tags: django

buenas tardes, paso a explicar mi duda:

Necesito hacer 3 select y llenarlos con información de la base de datos, para luego realizar una consulta y renderizarlo en la plantilla en el mismo html. Adjunto cual es mi modelo y formulario para ver si me pueden ayudar con el armado de la vista.

models.py:

```
class Productos_Arg(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
pais = models.CharField(max_length=50)
id_periodo=models.IntegerField(default=0)
periodo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
PrecioCompra=models.FloatField()
PrecioRenovacion=models.FloatField()

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s %s %s' %(self.nombre,self.pais,self.periodo,self.PrecioCompra,self.PrecioRenovacion)

class Meta():
    verbose_name_plural='Productos'
```

forms.py:

```
class ConsultaForm(forms.Form):
    Producto=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Productos_Arg.objects.values_list('nombre', flat=True).distinct('nombre'), label='')
    Pais=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Productos_Arg.objects.values_list('pais', flat=True).distinct('pais'), label='')
    Periodo=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Productos_Arg.objects.values_list('periodo', flat=True).order_by('id_periodo').distinct('id_periodo'), label='')



    def __init__(self,*args,**kwars):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwars)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class':'form-control',
            })
            self.fields['Producto'].empty_label="Seleccione un plan"
            self.fields['Pais'].empty_label="Seleccione un pais"
            self.fields['Periodo'].empty_label="Seleccione un periodo"
```

Pagina.html:

[image: Sitioweb.html]

Como ven ya tengo armado los 3 select y con las opciones que deseo. Lo que me falta es armar la vista para que me devuelva una consulta a la base de datos dependiendo de las opciones elegidas en el select ( He armado una única tabla para aun no meterme muy de lleno con los joins, quiero primero poder resolver esto que es mas sencillo para luego si intentar normalizar la base de datos y hacer consultas relacionadas ).

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar, se los voy a agradecer.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

De esta manero yo filtro en una lista los donantes que tinen un determnado factor y un determinado grupo que una tbal de bd, las opciones del factor y grupoe estan en dos select

```
class DonadorLista(ListView):
    model = Donador
    template_name = 'donante/donante_list.html'
    queryset = Donador.objects.order_by('-activo')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lista_donante')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(DonadorLista, self).get_queryset()
        filter1 = self.request.GET.get("grupo")
        filter2 = self.request.GET.get("factor")
        if filter1 == 'A' or filter1 == 'B' or filter1 == 'AB' or filter1 == '0':
            queryset = queryset.filter(grupo_sanguineo=str(filter1))
        if filter2 == '+' or filter2 == '-':
            queryset = queryset.filter(factor_sanguineo=str(filter2))
        return queryset
```

Comment: De esta manero yo filtro en una lista los donantes que tinen un determnado factor y un determinado grupo que una tbal de bd, las opciones del factor y grupoe estan en dos select